# How can a UITableViewCell know of its own indexPath?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

The standard Grouped `UITableView` style allows `UITableViewCell`s to be drawn with rounded corners at the top and bottom of each section.  How is this accomplished?  How does the cell know its own location within its section, and how does it know when to change its rounded edges?

I want to make my own rounded cells, and I have images to use, but don't know when to show which image

**Note:** I already know how the UITableView works, and I know how to use it.  I just thought that since a UITableView is able to automatically draw rounded corners at the correct places, I should be able to as well, without needing to add anything to my data source or delegate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is `sectionLocation` method of `UITableViewCell` that returns integer telling you what you need:

- 1 - middle cell
- 2 - top cell
- 3 - bottom cell
- 4 - single cell

I had no issues using this in several production apps since 2010.

**UPDATE:** one of our binaries was automatically rejected recently (end of 2018) because we were using 'sectionLocation' property, so it's not a good option anymore.

Add something like this into your header files and you can use it:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MMMTableViewCellLocation) {

    MMMTableViewCellLocationUndefined = 0,
    MMMTableViewCellLocationMiddle = 1,
    MMMTableViewCellLocationTop = 2,
    MMMTableViewCellLocationBottom = 3,
    MMMTableViewCellLocationSingle = 4
};

@interface UITableViewCell ()

/** Undocumented method of UITableViewCell which allows to know where within section the cell is located,
 * so the cell can draw its borders properly. */
- (MMMTableViewCellLocation)sectionLocation;

/** Override this one to know when the value of sectionLocation changes. */
- (void)setSectionLocation:(MMMTableViewCellLocation)sectionLocation animated:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

Answer (score 61):

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [(UITableView *)self.superview indexPathForCell: self];
int rows = [(UITableView *)self.superview numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];

if (indexPath.row == 0 && rows == 1) {
// the one and only cell in the section
}
else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
//top
}
else if (indexPath.row != rows - 1) {
//middle
}
else {
//bottom
}
```

Comment: That's half the answer, but how does it automatically change its rounded corners as cells are moved around?

Comment: You can put this piece of code in layoutSubviews in your cell subclass.

Comment: This solution may won't work anymore in the future. You cannot predict that your UITableViewCell is the direct subview of it's tableview...

Answer (score 32):

It's very simple. suppose cell is the object, whose position is to be found out.

```
  UITableView* table = (UITableView *)[cell superview]; 
  NSIndexPath* pathOfTheCell = [table indexPathForCell:cell]; 
  NSInteger sectionOfTheCell = [pathOfTheCell section]; 
  NSInteger rowOfTheCell = [pathOfTheCell row];
```

Comment: That's not particularly helpful as it does not address the cell knowing when its own row changed or when it becomes the first or last or only row in a section.  I need a way to get a callback when those things happen.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
```

for this issue. In my example I am using this to scroll the cell (with custom content) to the top of the view.

Comment: except a UITableViewCell doesn't have a reference to its table.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more robust and general stuff, take a look at http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html - Matt Gallagher shows what you need, pretty effectively. He basically recreates UITableViewController from UIViewController, while adding ability to use your own custom graphics. I'm just working on applying this to one my projects, so far it looks it would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have found no solution to this problem, and have resorted to subclassing UITableViewController and UITableViewCell into a generic solution that I can extend as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do this in cell. Rounded corners are drawn in [tableView viewForHeaderInSection] and viewForFooterInSection.

The way I do it is to use Plain tableview style, then use these two views for roundness and cells are normal, no rounds.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?  I don't quit understand how that would work out.

Comment: In order to avoid the trickery of keeping up with what is 1st row and last row, I used section header and footer and draw rounded parts in there. This keeps the rows clean, with simple background image view. You basically need to carefully slice the design.
It's not applicable if you need to render row selections (you'll have to change header or footer when edge rows are selected), so I use this simple technique for stuff where selection is not needed. The benefit is that it's really easy o implement, in default UITableViewController.

Comment: That may work but it's not the preferred way to do it as the headers and footers might be needed for something else later. You can get the current cells indexPath by asking the UITableView indexPathForCell:cell. If it's 0 and the number of cells 1, draw rounded corners on all four corners, else if 0 draw rounded corners on top, else if > 0 but not number of cells -1 draw rounded corners on bottom, else no rounded corners (middle cells).

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into who draws what, you can know which cell is the last cell in its section inside of cellForRowAtIndexPath very easily.

You're passed in the indexPath of the cell you need to provide, right?  You're also passed the tableView.

call [tableView numberofRowsInSection:indexPath.section] and if it's == ([indexPath.row]-1) you know you're being asked to supply the last cell in that section.

At the time that cellForRowAtIndexPath is being called, the cell is guaranteed to be at the indexPath passed in.

Comment: Yes, but cellForRowAtIndexPath isn't called when moving a row or deleting rows.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon Darren's answer (which I found most useful, thanks Darren!), what you can do is to iterate through all of the superviews' until you find the parent UITableView. This should be future proof since you do not rely on a fixed hierarchy of views.

I use a recursive method that will return the UITableView if it finds one or return nil if there is none.

```
- (UITableView *)parentTableViewOf:(UIView *)view {
        Class class = [view.superview class];
        NSLog(@"Class : %@", NSStringFromClass(class));

        if([view.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
            return (UITableView *)view.superview;
        } else {
            return [self parentTableViewOf:view.superview];
        }

        return nil;
}
```

So far I've used this one and it seems to work without hiccups. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks!  I modified it to make sure it didn't infinite loop upon reaching UIWindow.
    - (UITableView *)parentTableViewOf:(UIView *)view {
        if ([view.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
            return (UITableView *)view.superview;
        } else if (![view.superview isKindOfClass:[UIWindow class]]) {
            return [self parentTableViewOf:view.superview];
        }
        return nil;
    }

Answer (score -1):

The cells dont know where they go...The table view has cells, You are the one telling the table view WHAT goes in the cell. You do this in the DataSource where you implement cellForRowAtIndexPath...The way this works :

An index path has a row and a section

For a grouped table view

A section pertains to a group, and a row pertains to 1 entry in that section,
the way UITableView knows how many rows are in a section and how many sections there are is the DataSources methods numberOfSectionInTableView and the method numberOfRowsInSection, this will make the right calls to cellForRowAtIndexPath,  it is up to you to recognize which section and row is being queried and you need to build your cell according to these specifications.

A good way to do this i s you can have a Dictionary with keys of section names and values of NSArray with the values that go in that section.

So you implementation for numberOfSectionsInRows would look like

```
return [[dictionary allKeys] count]
```

And the implmentation of numberOfRowsInSection would look like

```
NSString* key=[[dictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:sectionNumber]
  return [[dictionary objectForKey:key] count]
```

You can always refer  to the UITableView programming guide at http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Introduction/Introduction.html
Hope that helps

Comment: That's not a particularly helpful answer.  I already know how the UITableView works, and I know how to use it.  I just thought that since a UITableView is able to automatically draw rounded corners at the correct places, I should be able to as well, without needing to add anything to my data source or delegate.

Comment: The UITableView isnt drawning rounded corners, the UITableCell is made to look like that inside its draw method...

Comment: If  you want to have you own custom cells subclass UITableViewCell and make your customization in there, your question was not particularly clear i guess, sorry for all the comments

Comment: Yes, I know all that too.  My question, very specifically, is that since I'm in UITableViewCell doing the customization, how do I know which rounded corners to draw?

Comment: O i see, because you have different corners for different cells? Well what i can suggest i s passing in the indexPath to the cell and based on that it will know what to do. OR just create different subclasses of UITableViewCell and depending on the indexPath when u return them, make the appropriate one

Comment: Yes, I'm using my own backgroundImages.  I have one for a top cell, one for a middle cell, one for a bottom cell, and one for a single cell.  See my comments on TahoeWolverine's answer as to why passing in indexPaths is exactly what I don't want to do.

Comment: You are going to have to, magically having the table view what you want wont  work...

Comment: Sometimes, when the question is "how can I enter in a while(NO) ?", the not-possible answer can be the best. +1

Answer (score -2):

Simply add a property to your custom UITableViewCell (depending on implementation) class that contains an int, NSNumber, or an NSIndexPath specifying which one it is. In you're using a data structure instead, then put it in you element in that data structure.  Then you simply set the property when you create the data structure, something like elt.id=i, and then you access it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, something like if (elt.id == 0 || elt.id == n-1) where n is the number of rows in your section.

I might have totally missed your question, but if I did, just comment and I'll post again.

Comment: Yeah, you kinda missed the question.  I know how to statically tell the cell at creation time where it is.  However, that doesn't tell it if it's at the bottom of its section without telling it what table it's in.  Even then, the problem is the fact that it's static.  If I delete the top row, I need to notify the second row to reset itself.  I don't have to do this when using regular UITableViewCells.

Comment: Well in that case, you can just call reloadData, and cellForRowAtIndex path should be called once each for your remaining cells, at which point you can turn the rectangle 2nd and 2nd to last cells into rounded ones.