# How to call indexPath in another view?

Tags: ios, nsindexpath

I have two views `listOptionTable.m`(UITableViewController) and `listOptionCell.m`(UITableViewCell).

I'm trying to call the `deselectRowAtIndexPath` method in `listOptionCell.m` while I need to get indexPath so it can run.

Please how can I get the `indexPath` from `listOptionTable.m`?

listOptionCell.h

```
  listOptionTable *tableVC;
```

listOptionCell.m

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:NO];

    if (isSelected){

        [tableVC.tbl deselectRowAtIndexPath:`indexPath` animated:YES]; //I have to call indexPath in here.

    }
    else
    {
     ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194887/how-can-a-uitableviewcell-know-of-its-own-indexpath

Comment: Thanks @Erzékiel No I didn't see it I will check now.

Comment: you want to call deselectRowAtIndexPath: from you cell class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the behaviour of your cell is strange. Anyway you can do that trick:

1. Add property to your custom cell (listOptionCell.m):

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *indexPath;
   ```
2. Implement UITableViewDataSource method in listOptionTable.m like:

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
     listOptionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     // Configure the cell...
     cell.indexPath = indexPath;
     return cell;
   }
   ```
3. Now you can get indexPath in your cell:

   ```
   [tableVC.tbl deselectRowAtIndexPath:self.indexPath animated:YES];
   ```

The better approach is to declare custom protocol in your cell and then ask delegate to deselect row at index path.

Comment: May I ask should I write a code to run the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I've debugged it and it is not passing inside it. It is a cellView I can't delegate it.

Comment: In case of using static cells you can directly outlet (IBOutlet) your custom cell to controller and then set delegate and indexPath.